# Command file - wait for a file to be written

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I use a camera monitor (Blue Iris) which writes wmv's to a directory. At a certain point (on a timer), I want to run a command file that copies those files somewhere else. So currently my command file works but if a file is in the process of being written (by Blue Iris), I end up with a corrupted file. How can I make sure that the file has been completely written before the copy starts? Cheers Dave

Comment: A couple of things comes to my mind, but first, what is the file system on which the folder resides?

Comment: You could check the file size. When it stops changing assume it is done writing.

Comment: This is on Windows 10 x64

Comment: with which Operation System are u working. If you're using a Linux or Unix System you may have a look into lsof (if you don't know lsof have a look here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples)

Comment: As said - Windows 10 X64

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the file, rename it first.
If the file is open by another application you cannot rename it - the rename will fail.
This failure lets you detect that the other app is still writing to it.

Once the rename succeeds, then you can copy or move it to where you want it to be.